# Keyboard shortcut for "Show numbers" dictation command

Tags: high-sierra, siri, mojave, voice-dictation

I have difficulty using mice for a significant period of time due to hand problems, and especially have difficulty with clicking. I try my best to use the keyboard when possible, but switching between keyboard and mouse when I have to navigate to a part of the UI that isn't keyboard-shortcut friendly can be frustrating and painful.

I've tried using the built-in MacOS dictation and have been extremely happy, and am especially impressed with the "Show numbers" feature, which overlays numbers on the clickable items on the UI that I can just say. Saying "show numbers" every few seconds, however, becomes tedious.

Is there any way to assign the "Show numbers" feature to a keyboard shortcut, so that i can just get the overlay with a keyboard shortcut and say the relevant number? I've tried looking at the developer documentations on NSSpeechSynthesizer and NSSpeechRecognizer but I don't think they'll do what I'm thinking of.

I run a mix of High Sierra and Mojave machines, if that matters.

Thank you!